# Is it possible to store SQL Subquery in hidden item for report source of apex?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

Report Source

> select ID,:hidden_item_subquery from MyTable a;

Subquery Item Assign

> :hidden_item_subquery := "select col from Table2 where col = a.col";

Comment: I don't know, but I presume it would help if you described what you're trying to achieve. What's the purpose of the hidden item (apart from holding that SELECT statement)? Who/what puts value into it? That "hidden item subquery" must return only one value - otherwise you'll get TOO_MANY_ROWS error. Besides, what is "a.col" in that query? Shortly - I (we?) need more information. Meanwhile, did you consider using function that returns query as report source?